# Access to attributes of Class-based decorators with arguments

Tags: python, properties, python-decorators

Lets say I have a class based-decorator with an argument like this:

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrap():
            # something with self.arg
            func()
        return wrap
```

When I have a decorated function `foo`, I can do following:

```
deco = Decorator("ARG")
def foo():
    pass
foo = deco(foo)
deco.arg = "CHANGE ARG"
```

It is possible to access/change `deco.arg` in some way, if I go with the `@`-Syntax?

```
@Decorator("ARG")
def foo():
    pass

# How to change/access the arg-attribute?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a closure:

```
def Decorator(arg):
    class InnerDecorator:
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func
            # make arg an instance attribute
            self.arg = arg  

        def __call__(self):
            return self.func()

    return InnerDecorator

@Decorator("ARG")
def foo():
    pass
```

And then set the attribute on the function:

```
>>> foo.arg
'ARG'
>>> foo.arg = 'WOW'
>>> foo.arg
'WOW'
```

Comment: Why do you call it a closure?

Comment: @MarineGalantin I'm not sure if I understand your question. Wikipedia contains an article about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). It's a term that refers to a class/function (`InnerDecorator`) that binds to names (`arg`) based on an outer function (`Decorator`). However comments are not the right place to discuss these kind of tangential questions.